# Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $a, b$ are zero divisors of $R$ such that $ab$ is nonzero. Show that $ab$ is also a zero divisor of $R$.

Tags: ring-theory, solution-verification

I am going to show that

Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $a, b$ are zero divisors of $R$  such that $ab$ is nonzero. Show that $ab$ is also a zero divisor of $R$.

To show that $ab$ is a zero divisor of R, we proceed to find a nonzero element $x\in R$ such that $(ab)x = 0$. Since $a$ and $b$ are zero divisors, there exist nonzero elements $r$, $s$ ∈ R such that $ar = 0$ and $bs = 0$.
Now, consider the element $x = rs$. Note that $x\not= 0$ because suppose NOT, i.e. $x = 0$, then $rs = 0$, which would contradict the fact that $a$ and $b$ are zero divisors (We have $0 = a(rs) = (ar)s$ or $0 = b(rs) = (bs)r$ (since $R$ is commutative) and one of $r$ or $s$ would have to be zero).

Let’s compute $(ab)x$:

$(ab)x = (ab)(rs) = a(b(rs)) = a((bs)r) = a(0 \cdot r) = a \cdot 0 = 0$

Therefore, $ab$ is a zero divisor of $R$.

Sorry my proof looks clumsy and not sure it is correct or not. Can anyone kindly help me to have a look? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really only need to use $x = s$, as
$$
(ab)s = a(bs) = a\cdot 0 = 0
$$
It's a lot easier to show that $x\neq 0$ in this case. It isn't actually possible to show in general for $x = rs$. Consider, for instance, $\Bbb Z^3$ with $a = b = (1,0,0)$, $r = (0,1,0)$ and $s = (0,0,1)$. This means you can't just pick arbitrary $r$ and $s$, but instead be careful.

Comment: So in general, it is not be possible to show that $x\neq 0$ for an arbitrary choice of $r$ and $s$, then my proof collapse when I choose something not arbitrary?

Comment: I think I got it. The point is when we choose $x=s$, $s=x\not= 0$. This is arbitrary but somehow restricted.

Comment: @鈴木悠真 For arbitrary choice of $r$ and $s$, we could have $rs = 0$. In fact, thinking about it, I believe it is unavoidable in some cases. Consider $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^3)$, with $a = b = x$. Then $r$ and $s$ both have to be $x^2$, and their product will be $0$. And yes, that's the point of picking just one of them. We already know that it is non-zero. You could also pick $x = r$ if you want.

Comment: Sorry can you explain why $rs=x^4=0$?

Comment: @鈴木悠真 How familiar are you with the concept of quotient rings, like $\Bbb Z[x]/(x^3)$? Because if $x^4 =  0$ is a mystery to you, then I think you should come back when you have worked a little bit with them.

Comment: I have not learnt about it. Perhaps I come back after I have some reading. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should prove the more general

> Suppose $R$ is a commutative ring, $a$ is a zero divisor of $R$ and $b$ an element of $R$ such that $ab \ne 0$. Then $ab$ is a zero divisor of $R$.

Since $a$ is a zero divisor, there exists $x \in R \setminus \{0\}$ such that $ax = 0$. But then
$$(ab)x = (ba)x = b(ax) = b0 = 0 .$$